Firebase SMS verification failing with error code 39
I'm experiencing an issue with Firebase where SMS verification codes are not sent to some valid phone numbers. These numbers are able to receive SMS from other providers without any issues. The problem has been observed over multiple attempts on different days. Here are the details:
{
  "insertId": "-k92yxdd8v6y",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.identitytoolkit.logging.RequestLog",
    "methodName": "google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AuthenticationService.SendVerificationCode",
    "status": {
      "message": "Error code: 39",
      "code": 13
    },
    "request": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.SendVerificationCodeRequest",
      "phoneNumber": "+400730679600"
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "86.124.126.97",
      "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "FirebaseAuth.iOS/10.22.0 ro.afooddeployments.afood/3.4.0 iPhone/17.4.1 hw/iPhone14_5,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)"
    },
    "serviceName": "identitytoolkit.googleapis.com"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "identitytoolkit_project",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "ambrosia-e5ea3"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-06-17T08:49:19.981Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/ambrosia-e5ea3/logs/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com%2Frequests",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-06-17T08:49:20.859697728Z"
}

Steps to Reproduce:

Attempt to send an SMS verification code to the phone number
+400730679600 using Firebase Authentication.
Observe that the request fails with error code 39 intermittently.

What I've Tried:

Confirmed that the phone numbers are valid and can receive SMS from
other providers.
Attempted multiple times on different days to rule out temporary
issues.
Reviewed Firebase documentation and error codes but found no
specific details for error code 39.

Has anyone experienced similar issues with Firebase SMS verification? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
note that +400730679600 is my own test number

I have the same issue here, just curious are you in Romania? We noticed the same problem but only with one local operator in RO named DIGI. Can you test it and see if it happens always on the same provider?

yes, in romania and only with the DIGI carrier

did you manage to solve it in any way?

It looks like some providers are blocking SMS with URLs.
See https://www.twilio.com/en-us/guidelines/ro/sms
"Romanian mobile operators are blocking and filtering SMS content containing web addresses (URLs)."

Hello! I have the same problem in Romania, did you ever solve it?

Nope, i tried to contact both Google and the Romanian Provider but they don't want to fix the problem, the solution was implementing a custom login serverless flow using a custom sms provider, in my case was Newsman
